# How to make SQL statement (query) precompiled In SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, database-performance, sqlperformance

We have many small SQL queries in our asp.net application. Also we have some stored procedures in database.

We can not create stored procedures for each of those SQL statements.

How we can make those SQL queries precompiled, so that it neglects compilation time each time query executes? Give us small example for that.

Comment: [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc293623.aspx) may help more than a short example would.

Comment: If your query is being unchanged then there is a good chance that cached plan will be reused. If your query is a non-parameterized  adhoc with a different text on each call - then there is no chance to reuse cached plan. How can an totally _new_ query be "precompiled"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to have queries pre-compiled is using stored procedure and parametric queries. Whenever you run a query, SQL server keeps the compiled execution plan in cache so if a query is used often in your application, SQL server keeps it for longer time.

Note that this will not happens if you use ad-hoc queries. 
If query1 is even 1 character different than query2 SQL assumes they are 2 different queries.

So use parametric queries as much as you can. This also helps you to prevent SQL-Injection.

For having more structured db programming it's better to use stored procedure. SP's act like parametric queries and actually prevent you from using ad-hoc queries.

You can find many articles in web if you search about "SQL Sever Execution Plan Cache"

If you need deep understanding of these stuff, read this book:

**Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Internals**

This link gives you deeper information.

[Chaching Mechanisms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc293623.aspx)

Comment: Even stored procedures in SQL Server aren't "pre-compiled" - their execution plan is determined upon the first execution - like with an ad-hoc SQL query - and cached for subsequent executions. See [Pre-Compiled Stored Procedures - Fact Or Myth?](http://www.scarydba.com/2009/09/30/pre-compiled-stored-procedures-fact-or-myth/)

Comment: @marc_s, You are right. I didn't mean SQL server compiles the rpocs before executing them. It compiles them at the first execution and then keeps the execution plan, like parametric queries. Stored procedures have more chance to stay in cache rather than queries as their signature remains the same (like parametric queries). Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks

Comment: Again: a stored procedure and a **properly parametrized** ad-hoc query have the **SAME CHANCE** of their execution plan being kept in memory. But if the queries are *not* parametrized, of course, that puts more pressure on the plan cache, and thus plans might be kicked out more quickly - but there's no difference between stored procedure plans vs. ad-hoc query plans - the oldest (least used) plans go first

Comment: @marc_s, I don't agree. if we use SP or parametric query, from SQL Server view point, the same thing is running again and again. If a query runs 100 times, it has more chance to stay in cache than a query which executed 2 or 3 times. Isn't that right?

Comment: yes - but if you have a stored procedure that runs 100 times, and a properly parametrized query that **also** runs 100 times - then both have the same chance of remaining in cache - the stored procedure doesn't have an advantage just based on the fact it's a stored procedure (vs. an ad-hoc query). That's what I'm trying to say: if the two are executed the same number of times, there's no advantage on the stored procedure side to remain in plan cache

Comment: I agree. SP has the same chance as parametric query, but Ad-hoc queries have much less chance. The good thing about SP is it always, behave like parametric queries, and prevents programmers write ad-hoc queries intentionally or unintentionally. I agree that I need to edit my answer to make it accurate. Right?